# Decanting code in $HOME/.bashrc into a function

Tags: bash, source

I have the following code fragment in my `$HOME/.bashrc` file:

```
export RED='\e[0;31m'
export GREEN='\e[0;32m'
export YELLOW='\e[0;33m'
export BLUE='\e[0;34m'
export MAGENTA='\e[0;35m'
export CYAN='\e[0;36m'
export WHITE='\e[0;37m'
#
export BOLD_RED='\e[1;31m'
export BOLD_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
export BOLD_YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
export BOLD_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
export BOLD_MAGENTA='\e[1;35m'
export BOLD_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
export BOLD_WHITE='\e[1;37m'
#
export BLACK='\e[\030'
export RESET_COLOR='\e[m'
export RESET_TERMINAL_COLOR="tput sgr0"
```

I want to modularize it as a function that is callable from all scripts.

I have removed the code from my `$HOME/.bashrc` file and made a file in my executable path called `colorize-terminal` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
function colorize-terminal {
[The code above goes in here]
}
```

and tried `source colorize-terminal` in a script to test it. But it does not give the expected colorization.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION: based on the comments below and what I found out**

1. I needed to rename both the function and the file `colorize-terminal` to replace the hyphen by an underscore so: `colorize_terminal`. AFAICT, shell-script names are accepting of hyphens but this is not so for functions. They accept underscores instead.
2. I needed to add `colorize_terminal` as the last line in the file.
3. After sourcing the function file, I tested it with `echo -e ${BOLD_YELLOW}"Hello there!"${RESET_COLOR}` and it worked as expected.
4. If I needed color upon login, I could source the file in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: Don't put it in a function, just cut/paste the code as-is into your new file. If you are going to put it in a function for some reason then add the call to that function within the same file.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when sourcing? Are you expecting that to actually change the colors, or are you expecting the new function `colorize-terminal` to now be available in your current shell session? Finally, how does it fail? You say "it does not give the expected colorization", so what happens? Nothing? Different colors than you expected? Something else? Please [edit] your question and explain what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: Oh, and remember that `source` is a non-standard bash thing. The portable, standard command for sourcing a file is `.` so `source` won't work if you're not using bash.

Comment: .... ditto for `function colorize-terminal {` vs `colorize-terminal() {`

Comment: There were two errors: (1) No hyphens are allowed in the function name. So, I renamed the file and function to `colorize_terminal`. (2) I included the function name as the last line of the file. Once these two were done, it works. Tested like this: `echo -e ${BOLD_YELLOW}"Hello there!"${RESET_COLOR}`. Since I am explicitly invoking `bash`, I prefer `source` to `.` and `function colorize_terminal` to `colorize_terminal ()`.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please offer that as an answer by writing it in an answer form below. This would allow you to accept your self-answer later, marking the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Kusalananda, here is my solution.

1. As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115082) a function name can only consist of letters, numerals, and the underscore character. The hyphen is not permitted. So, `colorize-terminal` needed to be renamed as both a file and a function to `colorize_terminal`.

The `bash`-specific working code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function colorize_terminal {
export RED='\e[0;31m'
export GREEN='\e[0;32m'
export YELLOW='\e[0;33m'
export BLUE='\e[0;34m'
export MAGENTA='\e[0;35m'
export CYAN='\e[0;36m'
export WHITE='\e[0;37m'
#
export BOLD_RED='\e[1;31m'
export BOLD_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
export BOLD_YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
export BOLD_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
export BOLD_MAGENTA='\e[1;35m'
export BOLD_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
export BOLD_WHITE='\e[1;37m'
#
export BLACK='\e[\030'
export BOLD='\e[\033'
export RESET_COLOR='\e[m'
export RESET_TERMINAL_COLOR="tput sgr0"
}
```

Put that code into a file named `colorize_terminal`. Invoke it from within any script by specifying the path to the file so:

`source /path-to-colorize-terminal/colorize_terminal`.

Its definitions will be available to the script.

It may be tested with a simple one-line command like:

`echo -e "${BOLD_YELLOW}""Hello World!""${RESET_COLOR}"`

Ideally, one could have this functionality at startup by including a line like

`source "$HOME/bin/colorize_terminal"`

in the file `"$HOME/.bashrc`.